# Gazebo Won't Start

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason unknown to me, I cannot get Gazebo to open. I have had it working on this machine previously. I'm running ubuntu 12.04 with ROS fuerte. Any ideas?

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds wg_world.launch
... logging to /home/allenh1/.ros/log/48b61258-d682-11e1-8c5b-0025648c1ab0/roslaunch-muri-pc7-5276.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://129.59.89.109:33072/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time
 * /wg_walls

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    xml2factor_wg_walls (gazebo/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [5292]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.59.89.109:11311

setting /run_id to 48b61258-d682-11e1-8c5b-0025648c1ab0
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5305]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [5319]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[xml2factor_wg_walls-3]: started with pid [5327]
[ INFO] [1343239086.118034332]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 5319, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/allenh1/.ros/log/48b61258-d682-11e1-8c5b-0025648c1ab0/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/allenh1/.ros/log/48b61258-d682-11e1-8c5b-0025648c1ab0/gazebo-2*.log
loading model xml from ros parameter
```

Here's with the empty world:

```
allenh1@muri-pc7:~$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/allenh1/.ros/log/88f94a4c-d682-11e1-87a0-0025648c1ab0/roslaunch-muri-pc7-5779.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://129.59.89.109:36018/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    empty_world_server (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [5795]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://129.59.89.109:11311

setting /run_id to 88f94a4c-d682-11e1-87a0-0025648c1ab0
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5808]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[empty_world_server-2]: started with pid [5822]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [5830]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1343239193.941097028]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[empty_world_server-2] process has died [pid 5822, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=empty_world_server __log:=/home/allenh1/.ros/log/88f94a4c-d682-11e1-87a0-0025648c1ab0/empty_world_server-2.log].
log file: /home/allenh1/.ros/log/88f94a4c-d682-11e1-87a0-0025648c1ab0/empty_world_server-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39788/gazebo-won%27t-start/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`wg_world.launch` uses HeightMap, which is broken in the release (should be fixed in next release 1.6.12).

For now, you can try using the meshed version?

roslaunch gazebo_worlds wg_collada_world.launch

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a similar setup (Ubuntu 12.04, updated gazebo package, previously working), but the final error I'm getting is "Illegal instruction (core dumped)".

After seeing what runs and what doesn't, it seems to be an issue with gzserver.  I ran gzserver inside gdb with a roscore running, and backtrace points vaguely to the physics engine:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffb57fa700 (LWP 16593)]
0x00007ffff7bc5f01 in gazebo::common::Time::Set(double) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_common.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bc5f01 in gazebo::common::Time::Set(double) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_common.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff7455d8d in gazebo::physics::World::Step() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_physics.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff74560c8 in gazebo::physics::World::RunLoop() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_physics.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff6a40ce9 in thread_proxy ()
   from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#4  0x00007ffff6c54e9a in start_thread ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff58ec4bd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

But a workaround I've found is to move the current simulator_gazebo stack ouside of where ROS can see it, and to svn checkout the [simulator_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) stack into your ROS path and rosmake the stack.

```
roscd simulator_gazebo
cd ..
sudo mv simulator_gazebo ~/simulator_gazebo_bak     #(or someplace else out of the way)
cd ~/ROS     #(or somewhere in your ROS path)
svn checkout https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk simulator_gazebo
cd simulator_gazebo
rosmake
```

After this, gazebo works for me.  I'm currently thinking the reason why it didn't work was because of how the .deb packages were made (a compile flag somewhere) but I don't know for sure.

---

Originally posted by [peekemaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2950/peekemaa/) with karma: 11 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-09-13**:
As of now rosmake is giving error as:

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nirala/fuerte_workspace/gazebo'
mkdir -p build
if [ ! -f md5sums/gazebo-r7e81d745eb07.tgz.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file md5sums/gazebo-r7e81d745eb07.tgz.md5sum" && false; fi